# iOS Core-plot: How can i start labels on y-axis from a certain value?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I am using core plot to generate graphs for some NUMBERS vs dates, I want to start labels on y from minimum NUMBER(or close to minimum) like IMAGE 1.[image]

I landed up in doing this with range.

```
plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(location:minimumValue-10,length:maximumYaxisValue-minimumValue+20)
```

[image: IMAGE 2]

All i want to do is to get the minimum NUMBER as the starting label on y-axis (or close number like in image 1)

I have tried many things but nothing worked out, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: What labeling policy does the y-axis use?

Comment: @adi how did you changed x-axis labels, can you share some code for that they are not changing for me ?

Comment: @Eric Sorry for the late reply, i actually changed the library to get it done. I was using LocationsProvided policy, which gave me desired result but the plot symbols were not showing completely...had to expand the range of the graph, which dint work out completely for me ....instead changed the library :(

Comment: @ali  this is the code i am using, let me know if you need any kinda help on this,
  ' xAxis.majorIntervalLength   = "Dynamic interval"  ;   
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();   
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd";   
            let timeFormatter = CPTTimeFormatter(dateFormatter:dateFormatter) ;   
            timeFormatter.referenceDate = oldestDate; // Starts from oldest date in my data     
            xAxis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;